# twists of unipotent algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $U$ be a unipotent linear algebraic group over some field $k$ with char$k$=0. Let $U'$ be a linear algebraic group over $k$ such that $U'_{\bar{k}} = U_{\bar{k}}$ (ie $U'$ is a $\bar{k}/k$-twist of $U$).

> Is $U'$ also unipotent?

Comment: As your base field $k$ is perfect and   you consider only smooth connected group schemes (or do you?), not only is your group $U^\prime$ unipotent, it even has a composition series whose successive quotients are $\mathbb G_a$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Unipotence is (by definition) a "geometric" property.

Take a look at page 3/52 of

http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~jtong/Recherche/Unipotent.pdf